# Convergence when integrating a not-quite power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a question where I don't have serious doubts about the *truth* of the statements; it's more about how to prove things rigorously.

Consider $\displaystyle\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}$ where $t$ may be a non-integer. We can write it as a geometric series
$$
\frac{1-x^t}{1-x} = (1-x^t) + (x-x^{t+1}) + (x^2-x^{t+2}) + \cdots
$$
and then integrate formally, giving us
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^t}{1-x}dx & = \Big[ \Big(x-\frac{x^{t+1}}{t+1}\Big) + \Big(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^{t+2}}{t+2}\Big) + \Big(\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^{t+3}}{t+3}\Big) + \cdots \Big]_0^1 \\
& = \Big(1-\frac1{t+1}\Big) + \Big(\frac12-\frac1{t+2}\Big) + \Big(\frac13-\frac1{t+3}\Big) + \cdots \\
& = \frac{t}{1(t+1)} + \frac{t}{2(t+2)} + \frac{t}{3(t+3)} + \cdots = t\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+t)}
\end{align*}
and this last series converges (it can be compared to the sum of reciprocals of the squares).

I am just wondering about the details if we wanted to make every step 100% rigorous. Weird things happen at the endpoint $x=1$, and it's not completely obvious to me that the series I wrote down for the antiderivative is a convergent series (nor that the "right things" happen when we naively plug in $x=1$).

Sometimes, one can just quote existing results (along the lines of "power series can be integrated term-by-term inside the interval of convergence, and an endpoint is well-behaved if the original series converges at that endpoint"), but it's not obvious whether we can do that here, since the original series is not actually literally a power series, due to $t$ not necessarily being an integer.

So, what's the best way to justify the above manipulations rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what's the best way to justify the above manipulations rigorously?

Monotonicity.

For $t \leqslant -1$, the integral does not exist due to a non-integrable singularity in $0$, but for $t > -1$ we have no problem.

The geometric series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has only non-negative terms, and the factor $1-x^t$ is either always negative ($-1 < t < 0$), identically $0$ ($t = 0$), or positive ($t > 0$) on the interval $[0,1)$. Thus by the monotone convergence theorem we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^t}{1-x}\,dt = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^1 (1-x^t)x^k\,dt = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+1+t}\right),$$

whether that is $-\infty,+\infty$, or a real number. Evaluating the series shows it is a real number.